# How to save a opened file in richtext box

Tags: c#

txt file in my richtextbox and want to save the orginal file rather than save a new file (SaveAs). here is my code for saving the file

```
private void SaveMyFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SaveFileDialog saveFile1 = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFile1.DefaultExt = "*.rtf";
        saveFile1.Filter = "RTF Files|*.rtf";          
        if (saveFile1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK &&
        saveFile1.FileName.Length > 0)
        {
          richTextBox1.SaveFile(saveFile1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
        }

    }
```

any help pleaseeee

Comment: please show the code where you open the file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try adding the file name or FileInfo from which the rich text is loaded from. If the file has not been saved, prompt to save the file. Otherwise, save to the file info cached.

```
partial class YourForm : Form
{
    string filePath;

    private void SaveMyFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
        {
            SaveFileDialog saveFile1 = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFile1.DefaultExt = "*.rtf";
            saveFile1.Filter = "RTF Files|*.rtf";          
            if (saveFile1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK &&
                saveFile1.FileName.Length > 0)
            {
                filePath = saveFile1.FileName;
            }
            else return;
        }

        try
        {
            richTextBox1.SaveFile(filePath, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            // Put exception handling code here
        }
    }
}
```

As per comment below, if you'd like a save as button, you can try the following:

```
partial class YourForm : Form
{
    Button saveFileAsButton; // Add this using the Forms Designer

    private void saveFileAsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog saveFile1 = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFile1.DefaultExt = "*.rtf";
        saveFile1.Filter = "RTF Files|*.rtf";          
        if (saveFile1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK &&
            saveFile1.FileName.Length > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                richTextBox1.SaveFile(saveFile1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
                filePath = saveFile1.FileName;
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                // Put exception handling code here (e.g. error saying file cannot be saved)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note how the setting of `filePath` is in the try block. In case the save failed, you don't want to lose your original file path.

If you form has a `MenuStrip`, I recommend moving the save functions into the menus.

(BTW, the type name for RTF in your filter would be better as "`Rich Text Document`".)

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you should don't want to present the dialog?  If so, just save the filename and save using that:

```
richTextBox1.SaveFile(_filename, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just save the file path when you open the file.. then lose all the SaveFileDialog stuff and just call richTextBox1.SaveFile(the_path_you_saved_when_you_opened_the_file);

Answer (score 0):

Just save the original path to the file that was read into the textbox. When the user clicks the button to save, use the following code:

`richTextBox1.SaveFile(filename, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);`

Where `filename` is the variable you stored the original path to the file opened.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that it sounds like you want:

```
String fileLocation;
private void SaveMyFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var performSave = true;
    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileLocation))
    {
        performSave = SetFileLocation();
    }
    if(performSave)
        richTextBox1.SaveFile(fileLocation, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);

}

private bool SetFileLocation()
{
        SaveFileDialog saveFile1 = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFile1.DefaultExt = "*.rtf";
        saveFile1.Filter = "RTF Files|*.rtf";          
        if (saveFile1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK &&
        saveFile1.FileName.Length > 0)
        {
          fileLocation = saveFile1.FileName;
          return true;
        }
        return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks for all the replies i will try 1 by 1 to see what works, but i am a real newbie lol i have just tried this one ^^^^ and got an error on debugging  ("Path cannot be null.
Parameter name: path)

Comment: thanks Justin can you also supply the detail to save as a txt file aswell please. also would it be better to createee a save button and a save as button as i want to save new files that i have written but have the choose to overright the orginal if i have opened it.